# Is there any feature in VueJS's v-for, using which I can force vue to not reuse data inside my components?

Tags: vuejs2

So, there are some Row components in my project. Every Row has a button below it clicking which should insert another row below it.

Each Row can contain multiple other elements which are represented using another array inside the Row component.

Whenever I try to add another row in any place, Vue just reuses the data inside that Row in the newly added component and shifts all others below it so it always looks like that where ever you click the 'row add' button it always gets added at the bottom.

Weirdly, when I use some sort of random shuffling function like rows.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), it rearranges the list randomly.

Here's the parent component which can contain any number of the Row components.

```
<template>
  <Row v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index"></Row>
</template>

<script>
import Row from "./Row.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Row
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      rowCounter: 0,
      rows: [{ name: "Row 0" }]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on("addRow", this.addRow);
  },

  methods: {
    addRow(rowCount) {
      this.rowCounter += 1;
      this.rows.splice(rowCount + 1, 0, {
        name: `Row ${this.rowCounter}`
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And the code for Row component:

```
<template>
 <!-- Just some dynamic components which can be added here -->

</template>

<script>
methods: {
  addRow() {
      this.$root.$emit("addRow", this.$vnode.key);
    },
}
</script>
```

The list should be rearranged but Vue just reuses the data inside the component.

I don't know what I am overlooking here but it would be great if you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and state in clear what is the desired behavior. Make it possible for anyone trying to help to be able to reproduce the problem without having to make assumptions.

Comment: You need a unique key for each row like: `:key="row.id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism is `:key` attribute but you need a unique key for each row like: `:key="row.id"`. The `index` is not unique identifier, since after `splice` (for example) it no longer points to the same row, but Vue can't know this.